# How do I match pairs in a 2 dimensional array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array with pairs of numbers and need to find matching pairs within the array

```
numberStore = [ [0,0],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5]... ]
```

I want to be able to find `1,4`. Is there a way to find this array without relying on `numberStore[4]`?

Comment: How often do you need to perform this search?

Comment: `numberStore.find(([a, b]) => a === 1 && b === 4)`? in the same way use `map` to update needed elements

Comment: Also, what _exactly_ do you mean by _"find"_? Do you want the index or just to know if the pair exists? Does the order of the pair matter?

Comment: Need to perform search frequently and need to know if it exists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you need to perform this search frequently, I would build a hashed set to avoid mapping and searching over and over. For example

```js
const numberStore = [ [0,0],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5] ]

const hashedSet = new Set(numberStore.map(pair => pair.toString()))
// looks like ["0,0", "1,1", "1,2", "1,3", etc]
console.log([...hashedSet])

const search = (find) => {
  return hashedSet.has(find.toString())
}

console.info('Find [1,4]', search([1,4]))
console.info('Find [4,1]', search([4,1]))
```

I've used `Array.prototype.toString()` as the hashing function but you could substitute anything there that creates a unique and comparable entity for each pair.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
var numberStore = [
  [0, 0],
  [1, 1],
  [1, 2],
  [1, 3],
  [1, 4],
  [1, 5]
];
var oneFour = numberStore.find(function([a, b]) {
  return a == 1 && b == 4;
});
console.log(oneFour);
```

Or if you prefer [ES6 arrow syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
var numberStore = [
  [0, 0],
  [1, 1],
  [1, 2],
  [1, 3],
  [1, 4],
  [1, 5]
];
var oneFour = numberStore.find(([a, b]) => a == 1 && b == 4);
console.log(oneFour);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is using the method [some()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_some.htm) to test elements for a condition.

```js
var numberStore = [
    [0,0],
    [1,1],
    [1,2],
    [1,3],
    [1,4],
    [1,5]
];

var exists = numberStore.some(([a, b]) => a === 1 && b === 4);

console.log(exists ? "Pair [1,4] exists" : "Pair [1,4] don't exists");
```